# What is the proper way to perform a maintenance flush on a water heater?

Tags: water-heater

Should I **completely close** the cold water inlet and attach a hose to the drain valve (located near the bottom of the water heater)? or should I leave the cold water inlet to the water heater **open** and drain from the bottom drain valve?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off power and close cold water inlet,

attach drain hose,

let it drain and observe the water contamination.

meanwhile open warm water faucet near it to assist the drain when pressure is down,

once all dirt is out open the cold water inlet to wash the rest out.

To fill it up, open cold water inlet and fill it up till water comes out of the nearby faucet to remove the air.

It is good water so capture it to water the garden.

Comment: Do I need to drain the entire tank, or 4-5 gallons will do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this as a yearly thing or is this year 5?

Flushing the tank can get rid of any sediment that has built up at the bottom of the tank and is slowing the transfer of heat to the water.  The heat ultimately still makes it to the water.  My water is very soft so maybe in hard water areas this is more important?

I don't see a big benefit in flushing the whole tank.  Even flushing the tank yearly seems like a bit of a waste of time.  Maybe doing it every couple years isn't a bad idea.  I had a gas hot water tank that I had going for 26 years (never replaced the anodes).  I finally removed it and switched to an electric hot water tank.  I should have switched to a hybrid.  Over the 26 years, I flushed it three times by just letting water out of the bottom until it went clean, only closing the cold water inlet so that the water wasn't shooting out under pressure.